# Ionic 4 - Cordova Plugin Fingerprint AIO - Disable face recognition (Fingerprint All-In-One)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins

I'm using [Fingerprint AIO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio) for fingerprint authentication.
I can't find a way to disable face recognition.

`FingerprintAIO.isAvailable()` returns `'biometric'` when fingerprints or/and face are registered on device.

Is there a way to force using only fingerprints?

Comment: According to this doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio , why don't you do a check on the result of ```Fingerprint.isAvailable``` , and if it returns ```face```, you don't apply your method ?
Or is the plugin returning face even if there isn't face biometric?

Comment: @ShinichiKudo thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this function returns 'biometric'.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation:

```
  /*
  result depends on device and os. 
  iPhone X will return 'face' other Android or iOS devices will return 'finger' Android P+ will return 'biometric'
  */
```

isAvailable returns the type of authentication available on the device.

iOS will either return "finger" or "face"; if it's "face" you know that the phone only has FaceID and you can choose not to handle it.

Android P+ only returns "biometric", because Android native API doesn't make a distinction based on the "type" of authentication; each manufacturer is free to implement a biometric sensor (note that, as of today, I don't know of any Android device that handles the native biometric API with anything else than a fingerprint sensor. Doesn't mean that there isn't any, just that it's not widely available).

If a manufacturer implements an Iris Scanner, blood-scan, or any other type of biometric authentication, the library would need hundreds of valid values; hence why it's just "biometric" for Android.

General note; Recent (as of 2021) iPhones only have faceID and no fingerprint scanner; it would be really weird to disable biometric authentication for people with a newer smartphone.